# How to improve this regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an regex to find the part of a `<a href="">` within the innerHTML of a div.

```
      var b = this.innerHTML.match(/href="([^\'\"]+)/g);
      var c = b[0].split('#')[1];
      window.location.assign('#'+c);
```

and would like to get rid of the second line, the .split function. Is there a way to do this? Ideally, I'd like to keep the hashtag before the div, too:

The hrefs are allways like this (only the number is subject to change):

```
href="#div46" 
href="#div47"
...
```

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: @anubhava this gives me undefined

Comment: @vks I don't get it... ?

Comment: @Biffen how will I get the result else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
var b = this.innerHTML.match(/href=(['"])(.+?)\1/);
window.location.assign( b[2] ); // #div46
```

- Remove `g` flag to get all matched groups in resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = $("a").attr("href");
var myString = val.substr(val.indexOf("#") + 1)
alert(myString);
```

**[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/6hsLd8w9/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression for that:

```
// you can extract all fragments of an url like this:

var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
linkElement.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

linkElement.protocol; // => "http:"
linkElement.hostname; // => "example.com"
linkElement.port;     // => "3000"
linkElement.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
linkElement.search;   // => "?search=test"
linkElement.hash;     // => "#hash"
linkElement.host;     // => "example.com:3000"

// in case you already have a link, you'll don't have to create it - just 
// use the element and ask for hash - and you are done.
```